# NoClassDefFoundError FileFilter missing when running JxBrowser from OSGi

Tags: java, swing, osgi, jxbrowser

Getting an error when trying to create a `BrowserView`, appears to have issues finding `javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter`. I'm using Guice to instantiate my screens, but this should have no affect. When launching my application with the embedded browser I get the following:

```
ERROR [Init thread] 19:37:24 19/09/17: ExtensionLoading error cuased by
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView.<init>(SourceFile:73)
```

This is running with OpenJDK 1.8. I've double checked the JxBrowser bundle and it appears to be importing `javax.swing` correctly. Any suggestions on what to look for?

The full stack trace is as follows:

```
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:987)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1013)
at com.ur.injection.GuiceBuilder.get(GuiceBuilder.java:27)
at gui.main.MainPanel.initFlippablePanel(MainPanel.java:45)
at gui.main.MainPanel.<init>(MainPanel.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:85)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1013)
at com.ur.injection.GuiceBuilder.get(GuiceBuilder.java:27)
at gui.main.URGUI.<init>(URGUI.java:119)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:85)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1013)
at com.ur.injection.GuiceBuilder.get(GuiceBuilder.java:27)
at gui.main.URGUI$5.run(URGUI.java:222)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView.<init>(SourceFile:73)
at com.ur.g5.runscreen.G5RunPanel.initComponents(G5RunPanel.java:227)
at com.ur.g5.runscreen.G5RunPanel.<init>(G5RunPanel.java:85)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:85)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter not found by com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium [32]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1558)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1998)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 77 more
ERROR [Init thread] 19:37:24 19/09/17: ExtensionLoading error cuased by
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView.<init>(SourceFile:73)
at com.ur.g5.runscreen.G5RunPanel.initComponents(G5RunPanel.java:227)
at com.ur.g5.runscreen.G5RunPanel.<init>(G5RunPanel.java:85)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionPrCaused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView.(SourceFile:73) at com.ur.g5.runscreen.G5RunPanel.initComponents(G5RunPanel.java:227) at com.ur.g5.runscreen.G5RunPanel.(G5RunPanel.java:85) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:85) at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85) at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254) at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46) at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031) at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40) at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65) at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40) at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54) at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38) at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62) at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84) at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254) at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46) at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031) at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40) at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65) at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40) at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978) at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031) at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974) ... 49 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter not found by com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium [32] at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1558) at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79) at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1998) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ... 77 more ERROR [Init thread] 19:37:24 19/09/17: ExtensionLoading error cuased by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView.(SourceFile:73) at com.ur.g5.runscreen.G5RunPanel.initComponents(G5RunPanel.java:227) at com.ur.g5.runscreen.G5RunPanel.(G5RunPanel.java:85) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:85) at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85) at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254) at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46) at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031) at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40) at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65) at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40) at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54) at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978) at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031) at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)oxyFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:85)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1031)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
```

Comment: Seems that JxBrowser is NOT OSGi ready, as it doesn't specify that it needs the `javax.swing.filechooser` package, but only the `javax.swing` package. Hacking their MANIFEST.MF by adding it to the import section resolves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to [system requirements](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013733-system-requirements) JxBrowser doesn't support OpenJDK. It supports only Oracle, Apple, and IBM JDK/JRE.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be an issue running OpenJDK, but i'll keep it in mind as we do developer going forward. See comments above for the actual solution to the problem.